# Using SET in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-scripting

Hi I wanna make a file when user can generate a password. In file pass.php I have got md5 simply code. Everything working but evert time i must edit a batch file and put a new password there(newpasswordhere), I just wanna put this passowrd cmd, I think this will be "set" but how to use it?

```
@echo off

cd c:\

C:\Bitnami\wap\php\php.exe pass.php newpasswordhere

pause
```

Comment: Have you ever thought of reading the [documentation of `set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1) or typing `set /?` into a command prompt window?

Answer (score 0):

Use `SET` command with `/p` switch:

```
set /p "PSWR=Enter Password: "
```

Usage:

```
C:\Bitnami\wap\php\php.exe pass.php "%PSWR%"
```

Comment: Are you aware that you are literally assigning the string `"somepassword"` to the variable, including the quotation marks? you should rather use `set PSWR=somepassword` or the (unfortunately undocumented) quoted syntax `set "PSWR=somepassword"` (so special characters like `&` or `^` are protected)...

Comment: sorry, missed that. tnx

Comment: Sorry that solution is not working batch file do not ask me to put some passowrd - gererate "sompassword" exacly as password in that case...

Comment: @EylM: how is that space important? It works with or without. (Recommended syntax is `set /p "PSWR=Enter Password: "`)

Comment: @Stephan - I updated the answer to a recommended syntax. tnx